# Querying ld to find out where it is a shared library

Tags: linux, linker

I'd want to query the GNU linker (ld) in order to find out the path of a .so file.
I know that there are several directories where such a files are stored, but I would know if it is possible to do that directly querying the linker.

What is it, if any, the right way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not direct query, but you could use something like

```
ld -t -lm -lc -lfoo 2> /dev/null | tail -n+2 | sed 's!^[^/]*\(/[^)]*\).*$!\1!g'
```

It will list all libraries passed to ld.